# Javascript DOM: How can I get the class attribute value of an element in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

As follows, there is an `input` element on a web page.

```
 <input type = "text" class="text-input">
```

When I click it, the Javascript code will append another class attribute value `W_input_focus`such as:

```
<input type = "text" class="text-input W_input_focus">
```

Well, how can I get the class attribute value except the value appended by the Javascript when I click on the input? I use getAttribute('class') method to retrieve ,but it return all the values include the js appended.

It is an example, actually beforehand I do not know which value is set to class attribute in the html code and which value is appended by js. 
And How can I distinguish , Thanks!

**I have found a simple answer:**

```
$(input).trigger("blur").attr("class")
```

Comment: You mean you want to only retrieve "text-input" class?

Comment: How should the Output look like? What have you tried until now?

Comment: Yes, only retrieve "text-input".It is an example, and I do not know the Js will  append how many class attribute values.

Comment: I use getAttribute('class') method to retrieve ,but it return all the values include the js appended.

Comment: At what point do you need to retrieve the class? Are you writing another click event to get the class value?

Answer (score 1):

There's a `classList` API available for this kind of cases: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList . Check the link for examples.

It's well supported on browsers except IE (10+): http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

..but there's a polyfill for that: https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

**To extend this answer:**

What you apparently need is `Mutation Events / Observers` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). And especially `DOMAttrModified`, which will dispatch when your className is changed (i.e classes are added/removed).

Support is good except on IE(11+) and on Android browsers (4.4+): http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

...but fortunately on IE, you can use `onpropertychange` listener: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx.

**An Example (tested on Chrome, FF, IE10)**: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/eGbur/ --> check console for details.

Answer (score 0):

`element.className` should provide the class names in string format. You can use `String.split(' ')` to separate them by spaces (since classes *are* separated by spaces).

Comment: It is an example,  actually beforehand I do not know which value is set to class attribute in the html code and which value is appended by js.

Answer (score 0):

Every class you add from js it appends after the class name you already have. So you can get the classname, split it in " " and get the first element, which is the class name you had in the start.

Try

HTML:

```
<input type = "text" class="text-input">
```

JS:

```
//ADD SOME CLASSES
$( "input" ).addClass( "W_input_focus" );
$( "input" ).addClass( "class2" );
$( "input" ).addClass( "class3" );

//GET THE CLASS YOU WANT
$( "input" ).click(function() {

    var className = $('input').attr('class');
    var arr = className.split(' ');
    alert(arr[0]);

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zBGrt/4/)

With just JS you can try

HTML:

```
<input id="input" type = "text" class="text-input W_input_focus" onclick="getClass()">
```

JS:

```
function getClass(){
  var className = document.getElementById('input').getAttribute('class');
  var arr = className.split(' ');
  alert(arr[0]);
}
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/zBGrt/5/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (no jQuery):

```
function getClassNames() {
    var element = document.getElementById('spanId');
    var classNames = element.className; //String containing all the classes as they are given in the attribute
    var classes = classNames.split(' '); //Since classes have to be separated by a whitespace, this will return all 'single' classes
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="classNames.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <input type="button" onclick="getClassNames()" value="Get Classnames">
        <span id="spanId" class="class1 class2"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```